# How to resolve: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, angular

Hello: I am getting my feet wet with the MEAN stack. So i am using Angular to connect to an api.js file, which connects with my mongodb database. However, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.es5.js:800)
    at MapSubscriber.project (post.service.ts:19)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1229)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4140)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
```

post.service.ts file which is referenced in the error is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  result: any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getPosts() {
    return this._http.get("/api/posts")
      .map(result => this.result = result.json());
  }

  getPost(id) {
    return this._http.get("/api/details" + id)
      .map(result => this.result = result.json());
  }

}
```

The following is my api.js file. Even the console does not log the post.

```
router.get('/details/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Requesting post');
    post.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function(err, post) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error getting the post');
            } else {
                res.json(post);
                console.log(post);
            }
        });
});
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong here. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: where you are getting that error?

Comment: in the chrome console. however, i am not getting that error when i try to pull all the posts; only when i try to request for a single post

Comment: The thing you are expecting to return JSON is actually returning HTML, hence the `<` as the first character. It's probably a standard error page on the server hosting the API, either a 4xx or likely a 5xx. So the code on the server is likely failing, or the wrong route. You would be able to see what returns by checking the network tab in browser dev tools. Or add a `.do( response => console.log( response.text() ) )` before your `.map()`

Comment: @Neil i'm using mlab as my mongo repository. but i don't get this error when i request for all the posts. only when i request for a single post using id. so how can i resolve this.

Comment: try a rest client and send request to your api.. see if you are getting json response

Comment: I think you mean `this._http.get("/api/details/" + id)`. Otherwise you are requesting `details123` as opposed to `details/123`. And it's the latter form you want.

Comment: so no error with getPosts but error on getPost `getPosts() {
    return this._http.get("/api/posts")
      .map(result => this.result = result.json());
  }

  getPost(id) {
    return this._http.get("/api/details" + id)
      .map(result => this.result = result.json());
  }`

Comment: Look at the comment I just made. You have a typing mistake on the name of the URL in your service request message

Comment: @Neil yes thanks i fixed that mistake..it works now `getPost(id) {
    return this._http.get("/api/details/"+id)
      .map(result => this.result = result.json());
  }`

Answer (score 1):

your api missing some parts, assume you send request to `not found` post or `server error`, then you send back nothing or error html to client. so try to send message to client like:

```
 if (err) {
    console.log('Error getting the post');
    res.status(500).json({error: err.message, errorCode: /*some number code*/ 1101});
 } else {
      /* logic for not found maybe */
      // and logic for result
      res.json(post);
      console.log(post);
 }
```

and the url should be: `get("/api/details/" + id)`

Comment: yes.. thanks i fixed the url.. that is where i was going wrong

Comment: you could update your api as my example above, it can prevent future issue